# Possibilities to move file one folder to another on remte FTP server using python

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

Trying to move files one folder to another on remote server using python?

```
                      shutil.move(src,dest)
```

but did not work for me any other suggestion?
now trying with ftplib but could not find correct function.

Comment: Did you get any output?

Comment: It is there in the `ftplib` documentation. https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary

Comment: Yes pax, 'IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'

Comment: han,how to give source amd destination folder for this function?

Comment: You **cannot** use `FTP.retrbinary` to *rename* a file. Use `FTP.rename`, as the duplicate question shows.

Comment: Thanks its worked for me.